# python guess my number exercise marked wrong on edX

Tags: python, edx

The program works as follows: you (the user) thinks of an integer between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (not inclusive). The computer makes guesses, and you give it input - is its guess too high or too low? Using bisection search, the computer will guess the user's secret number!

My code:

## guess number using bisection

## Ask for an input of number from the user

```
high = 100
low = 0
correct = False
response = ""
user_number = input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
while (response != "c"):
    guess = int((high + low)/2)
    print("Is your secret number", guess, "?")
    response = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly")
    if not  (response == "h" or response == "c" or response == "l"):
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
    elif (response is "h"):
        high = guess
    elif (response is "l"):
        low = guess

print ("Game over. Your secret number was:", guess)
```

Currently the EdX website is marking my answer as incorrect, I checked the out put by trying input numbers such as 83, 8,42 it came out correctly as the edX website code's showing. Can someone give me some suggestions on where my code is flawed? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare strings, use `==`.

Comment: If you want integer division, use `//`, do not cast the result of the division to an `int` afterwards.